# Proving a set is closed using continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

## Question

> Given $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, show that, for any
>   $x,x',x''\in\mathbb R$, the set $$ A=\{\alpha\in[0,1]:\alpha f(x)+(1-\alpha)f(x')\ge f(x'')\} $$ is closed.

I have the following proof, but something doesn't feel quite right. In particular, do I still need to show that $\alpha^*\in[0,1]$? Could you please check and see if this proof is correct?

## Proof (Attempt)

Recall that a set is closed if it contains all its limit points; that is, if every convergent sequence in this set has a limit also in this set.

Let $\{\alpha_i\}$ be any arbitrary convergent sequence in $A$, with $\alpha_i\in A$ for all $i\in\mathbb N$. 
To show that $A$ is closed, it suffices to demonstrate that the limit of $\{\alpha_i\}$ is also in $A$.

Since $\alpha_i\in A$ for all $i\in\mathbb N$, we have 
$$
  \alpha_i f(x)+(1-\alpha_i)f(x')\ge f(x''),\qquad \forall i\in\mathbb N.
$$
Note that the LHS of the inequality is a continuous function of $\alpha_i$.
Since continuous functions preserve the order of functional limits---i.e. if $h,g$ are continuous functions and $h(x_i)\ge g(x_i)$ for all $i$, then $\lim_i h(x_i) =h(\lim_ix_i)\ge g(\lim_ix_i)=\lim_ig(x_i)$---it follows that the limit $\alpha^*$ of $\{\alpha_i\}$ must satisfy
$$\alpha^* f(x)+(1-\alpha^*)f(x')\ge f(x'').$$
This, by definition, makes $\alpha^*$ a member of set $A$.
As the choice of $\{\alpha_i\}$ is arbitrary, we conclude that all convergent sequences in $A$ has limits also in $A$, and therefore $A$ is closed.

Comment: I am confused a little bit here. I don't know how the function f matters here as, once X, X', X" are given, we are just talking about three constants f(X) etc. then it is really easy to conclude A is closed.  Hope some smart guys can help. Thanks.

Comment: Is that the entire statement of the question -- are $x, x', x''$ totally unrelated, and is $f$ not necessarily continuous?

Or do you have something like $x'' = \alpha x + (1-\alpha) x'$ and $f$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof works. Note that $\alpha^{\ast} \in [0,1] $ because you're taking $\alpha_i$ in $[0,1]$ that is a closed set. You could also say that $A = g^{-1}([0,+\infty))$ where $g (\alpha) = \alpha f (x) + (1-\alpha) f (x') - \alpha f (x'') $ that is a continuous function.